# Extração de dados de uma API - Python

Tags: python, api

Olá, estou tentando fazer a extração de dados dessa API: https://www.balldontlie.io/#get-all-stats com o seguinte código em python:

```
import requests
import json
import time

resultados_totais = []
paginas_totais_para_ler = int(11000)
contador_extra = 0

for page_num in range(1, paginas_totais_para_ler + 1):
    url = "https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?per_page=100&page=" + str(page_num)
    print("Lendo", url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    response.raise_for_status()
    resultados_totais = resultados_totais + data['data']
    contador_extra = contador_extra + 1
    print(contador_extra)
    if contador_extra == 59:
        contador_extra = 0
        print('tempo')
        time.sleep(60)

print("Temos um total de", len(resultados_totais), "resultados")

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as d:
    json.dump(resultados_totais, d, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Porém, sempre obtenho esse erro: (https://cdn1.gnarususercontent.com.br/1/292460/5c2858ca-33df-4bd8-9b44-0d50a48ab3e0.png)

A API deveria suportar 60 requests por segundo, as vezes até passa de 60, mas no final sempre dá esse erro. Alguém teria alguma sugestão para poder me ajudar?

OBS: Precisaria dos dados de todas as 11000 páginas do 'stats'

Comment: Diga o que exatamente deseja  extrair ou a precedências dos dados q sera lido e qual sua dificuldade de realizar a tarefa.

Comment: Para que a dúvida atenda ao objetivo do site é importante [edit] e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Soluções individuais, para códigos específicos não são adequadas para um repositório coletivo de soluções para um público amplo. Mais detalhes nos links e na [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refiz o código (cada pagina salva será idexada com o número dela no JSON, se você quiser pode diminuir o tempo de sleep...)

Deste jeito ele vai salvar a 'data' e 'meta' de cada página, depois de salvo o json é possível fazer uma separação mais rápida e personalizada dos dados...

```
import requests
import json
import time


def get_data(url_var):
    print(f'Getting data from {url_var}')
    data_var = requests.get(url_var).json()
    print('Ok...')
    return data_var


base_url = r"https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?per_page=100&page="
joined_data = {}

for x in range(1, 11000 + 1):
    data = get_data(f'{base_url}{x}')
    joined_data[str(x)] = dict(data)
    time.sleep(1)

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(joined_data, f)
```